# Can someone explain how does Typescript inferred the type of Generic T here?

Tags: typescript

How did typescript inferred that: T will be "basic" | "minimal" instead of the entire object passed. Can someone please explain how is this possible?
How does typescript infer types?

```
type TProjectionKeyValue = { [key: string]: 0 | 1 };

type PType = "basic" | "minimal";

const ProjectionBuilder = <T extends PType>(projections: { [key in T]: TProjectionKeyValue }, defaultProjection: string = "basic") => {
  const buildProjection = (requiredProjections: T[]) => {
    
  };

  return buildProjection;
};

const mainProjections = ProjectionBuilder({
  basic: {
    name: 0,
    kdldl: 1,
    jkjk: 0
  },
  minimal: {}
});

const x = {
  basic: {
    name: 0,
    kdldl: 1,
    jkjk: 0
  },
  minimal: {}
}
```

Comment: `T extends PType` already constraints `T` to `PType` which means it is at least `"basic" | "minimal"`. Why would/should it be the entire object?

Comment: So typescritpt doesn't infer from left to right? I thought it Will put a typeof value in T and then check it with PType

Comment: This isn't about inferring "from left to right".  From the code you've written, `T` is a key type.  You've [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to `PType` which is a key type, and you've used it as a key in a mapped type like `{[K in T]: ...`.  I'm not sure why you would expect `T` to be inferred as anything except a key type. What's the disconnect here?